# Both Linearly Independent and Dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

Is it possible for two vector functions of, for the moment's simplicity, one variable be both independent **and** dependent?

The reason I'm asking this is because on a problem from a book of mine (not homework), they put the following exercise:

*Let $x^{(1)}(t)=\left (\begin{array}{cc} e^t \\ te^t\end{array} \right)$ and $x^{(2)}(t) = \left ( \begin{array}{cc} 1 \\ t \end{array} \right )$ . Show that $x^{(1)}
(t)$ and $x^{(2)}(t)$ are linearly dependent at each point in the interval $0 ≤ t ≤ 1$.
 Nevertheless, show that $x^{(1)}(t)$ and $x^{(2)}(t)$ are linearly independent on $0≤t≤1$.*

I would think that they're linearly dependent because $x^{(1)}(t)$ can simply be divided by the scalar $\frac{1}{e^t}$ (this is allowed because it is a never-zero exponential) to be equal to $x^{(2)}(t)$ $\forall t$, but because of the question I'm not too sure.

Could you give me some insight and/or guidance?

Comment: $1/e^t$ is not a scalar, as your $t$ has to vary. You need to find a real number (real presumably) $\alpha$ such that $x^{(1)}(t)=\alpha x^{(2)}(t)$ for all $t$ to show they are dependent. Of course, this can't be done.

Comment: I added the tag (notation) because when it comes down to it, the problem is the notation.

Comment: @Arturo Don Juan Do you still need help with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bad notation is bad....

> Show that $x^{(1)}(t)$ and $x^{(2)}(t)$ are linearly dependent at each point in the interval $0 ≤ t ≤ 1$.

What you're being asked to prove here is that given $t\in [0,1]$, the vectors $x^{(1)}(t)$ and $x^{(2)}(t)$ are linearly dependent. There is nothing wrong with this.

> Nevertheless, show that $x^{(1)}(t)$ and $x^{(2)}(t)$ are linearly independent on $0≤t≤1$.

What you're being asked to prove here, is that the vectors $x^{(1)}, x^{(2)}\colon [0,1]\to \mathbb R^{2\times 1}$ (vectors as in elements of a certain vector space - for example that of functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb R^{2\times 1}$ - this vectors happen to be functions) are linearly independent.

That is, you're being asked to prove that $$\forall \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb R\left[\forall t\in [0,1]\left(\alpha x^{(1)}(t)+\beta x^{(2)}(t)=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix}\right)\implies \alpha =0=\beta\right].$$

Here the author is looking at $x^{(1)}(t)$ and $x^{(2)}(t)$ as if they were functions, which they are not. The notation is wrong. Correct would be:

> Nevertheless, show that $x^{(1)}$ and $x^{(2)}$ are linearly independent on $0≤t≤1$.

Comment: You mean to have a plus sign in between $\alpha$ and $\beta$, right?

Comment: @ArturoDonJuan I did, yes. Fixed it before your comment :P

Comment: Also, did you mean to put $\exists \alpha , \beta $, instead of $\forall \alpha , \beta $?.

Comment: @ArturoDonJuan No, that part is right. By definition, two vectors $u,v$ are linearly independent (over a $\mathbb F$-vector space $V$) if, and only if, $$\forall \lambda _1, \lambda _2\in \mathbb F(\lambda _1u+\lambda _2v=0_{V}\implies \lambda _1=0_{\mathbb F}=\lambda _2).$$ **Edit:** Are you using a different definition of linearly independence?

Comment: Oh yeah, woops. I was thinking of how the definition of linear dependence starts off.

Answer (score 2):

The question mixes two different vector spaces. You have two functions from $[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^2$,
$$
x^{(1)}\colon t\mapsto\begin{bmatrix}e^t\\te^t\end{bmatrix},\qquad
x^{(2)}\colon t\mapsto\begin{bmatrix}1\\t\end{bmatrix}
$$
These functions belong to the vector space $V$ of continuous maps from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ and form a linearly independent set in $V$. Indeed, if
$$
\alpha x^{(1)}+\beta x^{(2)}
$$
is the zero function, then it's easy to prove that $\alpha=\beta=0$ (just evaluate the functions at two suitable values of $t$). However, for each $t\in[0,1]$, you have $x^{(1)}(t)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and $x^{(2)}(t)\in\mathbb{R}^2$; it can happen that, for some value of $t$ or even for all values of $t\in[0,1]$, these vectors form a linearly dependent set *in the space $\mathbb{R}^2$*.

Comment: So for any **fixed** value of $t$, these two vectors form a linearly dependent set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ but **not** for all $t$ (the continuous mapping from the domain of $t$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$) because there doesn't exist an $\alpha$ and $\beta \backepsilon \alpha x^{(1)}(t) + \beta x^{(2)}(t) = 0  , \forall t$. Is that right?

Comment: @ArturoDonJuan Yes, that's the idea.